"Auto-renew failed: Vehicle is not available" error spam, but the vehicle IS available. How do I fix this?
I just upgraded my passenger lines to Dedicated High Speed Rail, and now I'm getting constant error messages about being unable to auto-renew them.  I don't understand; the depots are all the correct type, they maintain the trains properly, I can even buy the same exact trains from them.  I have tried deleting and rebuilding every depot, which did not help.  How do I fix this?  I am using the Ironhorse 3.19.0 NewGRF for my trains, if that makes a difference.
